# How can i build a google drive client app in GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, gnu, grive

i need to build a Google drive client in any GNU/Linux
it should sync files automatically from my directory and to my directory from Google drive
it should be client similar to grive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the **grive** documentation. This is a google drive client made for linux, I think this is what you are trying to do.

https://github.com/Grive/grive